# Airflow task separation

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to understand what the best 'Airflow way' DAG design would be for the following scenario.

I need to hit lets say ten different REST API endpoints to collect a different data payload response for each of those queries. Each data response needs to be written into data lake storage.

I had expected to approach this as follows:

Task #1 Gets payload one.
Task #2 Writes payload one into staging area of the data lake.
Task #3 Gets payload two.
Task #4 Writes payload two into staging area of the data lake.
....
Until all payloads have been written into the data lake.

The question is how do I pass the data payload from Eg Task 1 (which gets it) to Task 2 which needs to write it. The payload is too big to use an Xcom and in any case I realise that this is not really how Xcoms should be used anyway.

The alternative pattern is to combine tasks 1 and 2, 3 and 4 and so on.. but I really liked the idea of being able to track the concrete process of committing the data to the data lake as a distinct task.

My rationale for this is that the act of writing the data to the lake is not simple and involves extensive work, which seemed to justify it being a task in it's own right.

What's the correct approach to this situation? Would greatly appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@indrid. You need to use external data storage, something kind of like s3. Between tasks you will be sent only metadata, like file names.

Send data as files to ex storage. Send meta about data to xcom. In the downstream task, you should get meta from xcom. Get data from ex storage by this meta, like file names.